# NestJS Neo4j : Cannot find module 'neo4j-driver/types/integer' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: neo4j, nestjs

I try to run my nestJS but I've got a problem with my node_module :

node_modules/nest-neo4j/dist/neo4j.service.d.ts:10:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'neo4j-driver/types/integer' or its corresponding type declarations.

10     int(value: number): import("neo4j-driver/types/integer").default;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/nest-neo4j/dist/neo4j.service.d.ts:12:47 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'neo4j-driver/types/session' or its corresponding type declarations.

12     getReadSession(database?: string): import("neo4j-driver/types/session").default;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/nest-neo4j/dist/neo4j.service.d.ts:13:48 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'neo4j-driver/types/session' or its corresponding type declarations.

13     getWriteSession(database?: string): import("neo4j-driver/types/session").default;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 3 error(s).

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Neo4jModule } from 'nest-neo4j'

@Module({
  imports: [
    Neo4jModule.forRoot({
      scheme: 'neo4j',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 7687,
      username: 'neo4j',
      password: 'ingrid-ticket-capital-spirit-reform-6035'
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Is any one got the same error ?

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: What version of `neo4j-driver` are you using? I wonder if you specified a recent version that is not compatible with nest-neo4j.

Comment: @fbiville

`"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.15",

    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.15",

    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.15",
    "neo4j-driver": "^4.3.1",
    "nest-neo4j": "^0.1.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6"`

Answer (score 0):

You should either downgrade the `neo4j-driver` to 4.1.0 (that's what `nest-neo4j` 0.1.4 has been tested with) or...
remove `neo4j-driver` entirely from your direct dependencies, since `nest-neo4j` already depends on it. That way, nest-neo4j is always responsible for the driver version it works with, avoiding conflicts like this.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem !